# TensorFlow Object Detection tutorial program can't find string_int_label_map_pb2

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to install TensorFlow Object Detection on my PC which is Windows10, after finished all the installation steps, I tied to run tutorial program, but I told me there is a import problem

ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'

I have run the

protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

My python is 3.6.2, protoc version is 3.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have run the command in CMD without "python" at front, after I add python it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the PYTHONPATH variables and point them to the object_detection folder. You can run the below command:

```
set PYTHONPATH=path\to\object_detection\models;path\to\object_detection\models\research;path\to\object_detection\models\research\slim;path\to\object_detection\models\research\object_detection
```

replace the "path\to\" with your actual path. After you have done the path setting, restart the jupyter notebook and try runnning again. You should not see the error. Hope it helps.